# moving site cannot see templates

Tags: ee2, server-migration, hosting, localhost

So on my local server I can see my templates

http://mylocalhost.com/site/aboutus

I moved my site to another (staging server) and these templates have disappeared.

Any ideas? I have updated the Server path to site's templates and have synced the templates and all is good there.

edit: created a test template and /site/test is not visible either

Comment: I'd happily look into your CMS for you if you like. Could you share login credentials for the staging server with me?

You can email webdesign@andief.com

If I can fix it, I'll post back here with the answer.

Comment: Is your .htaccess file the same on both hosts? Have you tried adding index.php to your url?

Comment: Does that mean that you can not see the templates on the front end of the site or in the control panel?

And mjr, that should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the replies it was not an EE error but a problem with the mod_rewrite on the Apache server

Answer (score 0):

Although you already mentioned your what your answer was. Always follow the steps described on this page.

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/operations/moving.html